# Does the return keyword in C stop the compilation of next statement or just the execution?

Tags: c, return

Here is my code in C Language:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("This line is written before return keyword.");
    return 0;   //terminator

    printf("This line is written after return keyword."); //does not display
}
```

I know that anything written after a return keyword in a function will not be executed. My question is, "Does the code after return keyword be compiled in the first place?"

Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Unreachable code will most likely be optimized away. But it is compiler dependent.

Comment: Can you be more clear please? Eugene Sh.

Comment: @BhanuPrakash No, yes, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the code is compiled and the compiler can issue an error if the code is invalid.
Also it can issue a warning saying that the code after the return statement will not be executed.

The compiler is allowed not to generate object code for such unreachable code.

Comment: Thank you Vlad. I was just curious. Should have tried putting a bad code below it to test...